# Is Guava's HashFunction threadsafe?

Tags: thread-safety, guava

Is HashFunction in Guava library Threadsafe?

```
static HashFunction hashFunction = Hashing.sha256();

private static String getHashCredentials(String String) {
    return hashFunction.newHasher()
        .putString(String, Charsets.UTF_8).hash()
        .toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you're using built-in `HashFunction`s, they're pure function -- see the [documentation page for `HashFunction`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/HashFunction.html):

> A hash function is a collision-averse **pure function** that maps an
>   arbitrary block of data to a number called a hash code.
>
> Unpacking this definition:
>
> - (...)
> - pure function: the value produced must depend only on the input bytes, in the order they appear. Input data is never modified.
>     `HashFunction` instances should always be stateless, and **therefore
>     thread-safe**.

Bear in mind that because `HashFunction` is an interface, you *could* create stateful and non-thread-safe implementation, but it would break the contract.